# Asking advice about an old book

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there someone who has read  Roman Maeder's "Programming in Mathematica"? Is it useful or outdated for a user of WM8? Please provide me some comment over this old book.

Answer (score 9):

It is still one of the best books on Mathematica programming, emphasizing good programming style and practices (pick the 3rd edition though - was published in 1996). [Here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node284.html) you can find my opinion on this book in  a bit more extended form.

Just be aware that what you will find in Maeder's book is a very elegant description of the *core* language, but not of many more modern additions. Important things regarding the core language which you *won't* find there include:

- Packed and sparse arrays
- Integrated string manipulation operations
- `Reap` and `Sow`
- Modern ways of treating options: `OptionsPatern`, `OptionValue`, `FilterRules`.
- Mathematica compiler (`Compile`)
- Not much advice on performance - tuning (there is some, but this is not heavily emphasized)
- Not much advice on debugging

Also, the core language aside, it contains no coverage of anything that was added to the language after 1996 (that would include dynamic interactivity, parallel computations - which is ironic since this part has been developed by Maeder, new areas of integrated functionality, new capabilities of `Compile`, etc).

Nevertheless, I highly recommend this book. In my opinion, it can be called "Zen of Mathematica programming". It is not quite an easy read, and I think I read (parts of) it at least 10 times with each time understanding something that wasn't apparent to me before (may be it is just me being dumb). This is also a great resource for writing packages, and in this capacity probably still unsurpassed. I would not recommend it as a first book on Mathematica, but you will be missing a lot not having read this book.

Comment: You wrote "Here you can find my opinion on this book in a bit more extended form" with the link to rather a bit too shrinked opinion.

Comment: @Artes Docendo I first thought of just leaving a first paragraph above only, as the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Leonid Shifrinless and Artes Docendo,especially the detail comment of Leonid Shifrinless!I plan to buy this book to improve my programming skill of mathematica after reading Mathematica Navigator: Mathematics, Statistics and Graphics, Third Edition

Comment: Do you think this book is still worth getting for people with a bit more experience?  Do you know any newer books which also focus on the core language rather than specific functionality?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, absolutely, this book is worth attention also for people like us. As for the newer books - my idea was to write such a book, and it is in progress. I've heard that Sal Mangano's M cookbook has some good parts, but did not have a chance to check myself. David Wagner's book is great, but also from 96. Other than these, no, I am not aware of anything focusing *only* on the core language for more intermediate / advanced / expert users. There are certain challenges in writing a more advanced M book, at least I find it a much harder task than writing my previous one.

Answer (score 3):

This is at least unsatisfactory, that there are no newer books on the core language, as well as even no newer editions of the books by Wagner and Maeder. I read "Programming in Mathematica" 3 years ago only once since I borrowed it for 2 weeks, but my pure impression was that I really needed that top expert's book. Strictly to the question:  it is not only useful for a WM8 user, but  the more M-functionality  gets larger I believe the more one needs read that classic book, since it presents pure M-fundamentals rather than deals with details of specific implementations, which today is still more important for such a comprehensive system.

His (R.Maeder's) another one "Computer Science with MATHEMATICA" is very good and almost 12 years old, but rather not targeted the M core.

I find Sal Mangano's M Cookbook to be good newer one for an intermediate reader,
its drawback is that it is a bit mixed up, and its style is not very convenient for deeper understanding.

The third edition of Mathematica in Action by S.Wagon is a really beautiful book,  but rather about Mathematica applications. Someone wrote about it that there every page was gold and I am close to that opinion.

An impressive 4-volume book by M.Trott had to be updated with dynamic interactivity and other new functionality in versions 6+, but on its web page one can read "August 2008: Although Mathematica Version 6 has been released, updating the GuideBooks is taking longer than predicted. So, rather than having new versions in Summer 2008, the expected date is sometime in 2009". 
  Up to now there is no newer edition.

Taking all above into account I find Leonid Shifrin's book is very needed to Mathematica community and I hope there will be also paper editions.

I find that in all M-books, chapters about pattern matching and rule-based programming are rather too brief, while the common opinion is that Mathematica fullest potential can be used only with mastering both functional and pattern-based programming, and they both are worthy even a whole monograph.

Comment: ,I agree with your viewpoint that the publication of the book on Mathematica is always later than the update of the software.

Comment: A good way of tracking up-to-date programming styles and functionality in Mathematica is exploration of newest programs on Wolfram Demonstration Project.

Comment: You are right. Wolfram Demonstration Project is a good source of knowledge,but it is hard for a newer like me to understand.

Comment: In general there are easier and harder pieces of code, over 7500 demonstrations. If you browse a bit you'll find very interesting and not too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Should you decide to read Roman's books you will be left with a very solid basis of *Mathematica*. I read two of them (PIM and CSM), and like them for their elegant and succinct style, both in programming and language. I have had the pleasure of giving talks together with Roman and I know very few people that have such an in depth understanding of the *Mathematica* language. Roman was one of the initial designers of the Language. My two cents. Don't walk but run to get copies.

Comment: Well said, Oliver! I have all (4) of Roman's books (PIM, Computer Science with Mathematica, and both Mathematica Programmer I and II), and consider these perhaps the most valuable books on my Mathematica bookshelf. +1.

Comment: @ruebenko,thanks for your reply.After reading Mathematica Navigator: Mathematics, Statistics and Graphics, Third Edition , I want to find a book to help me improve my programming skill. I find programming in Mathematica is a good choice,but it is published in 1996 .

Comment: Is there any book for M that touches on the aspect of programming in the large vs programming in the small? Everything I see it oriented towards small examples and how to solve a small stand alone problems. But little about how to put all these pieces together to build a really large application. When it comes to designing large application using M, I see nothing in this area.

Comment: @Nasser M. Abbasil At present there is no book satisfying your need because of the universal and complex characters of Wolfram Mathematica ,I think.

Comment: @esetlzn, the books are very valuable since they teach you the fundamentals *with* blur, Roman is very focused. If you understand these issue building large problems is not the issue. I read these two books and SICP and wrote the IMTEK Mathematica Supplement, which is several thousand lines of code. They helped me a lot.

Comment: @Nasser, please see comment above.

Comment: @ruebenko, I tried to download your IMTEK Mathematica software many times, using firefox from https://simulation.uni-freiburg.de/downloads/ims but no luck. Can't download the .exe nor the tar files. save as target or just a click on the links, gives errors. EIther timeouts, or error that file can't be downloaded. Is there other location to download your software from? thanks

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi give me a few days and i'll set something up.